# How do I mask out letters that don't match what's expected?

Tags: ruby, restrictions

My goal is to create a game of hangman. I wrote code similar to this:

```
c = []
players_guess = gets
b = "example"
b.scan(/./) {|letter| c << letter}

c.each do |letter|
  if letter == players_guess
    puts letter
  else
    puts "*"
  end
end
```

The code checks if the player guessed the right letter from the password hidden in variable `c`, and then displays the password hidden behind the `*`s and only revealed guessed letters. But when I run the program, the result is always the same, it displays `players_guess`, and then gives seven `*`. What is wrong here?

Comment: What is wrong is your expectation that something different would happen :) What hint do you need?

Comment: i expected eg if players_guess = "e" it will display "e*****e". but it gives "e*******". and it displays the players_guess at the beginning like this no matter what letter or number i choose:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do what you want:

```
word = "example"
puts "Type a letter: "
guess = gets.chomp
puts word.tr("^#{guess}", "*")
```

This uses the `String#tr` method to replace all but the guess to `*`.

The output if you typed `e` would be `e*****e`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your If/Then Logic is Wrong

Your code is as follows:

```
c.each do |letter|
  if letter == players_guess
    puts letter
  else
    puts "*"
  end
end
```

The conditional will generally be false, since no single letter is likely to match the entire line retrieved by `gets`. As a result, you get an asterisk printed for each letter in *c*.

#### Some Options to Fix Your Code

You can do a couple of things here.

1. Just show the string if the strings are equal.

   ```
   puts players_guess if b == players_guess.chomp
   ```
2. Use a counter in your loop to index into your arrays or strings.

   - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-index
   - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D
3. Split both strings into an array, and compare the arrays, printing letters that match or an asterisk on a non-match.

   ```
   c.each_with_index do |char, idx|
     puts char == players_guess.scan(/./)[idx] ? char : '*'
   end
   ```

Comment: i don't know the methods you used here, but thanks anyway, i will do my best researching:)